# C# Share custom handler method between razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Im working on a system where I have a few razor pages that all require some similar however still different logic. For the shared part I wrote a custom OnGet handler method that returns some objects.

Is there a good way to share this custom handler method between my razor pages instead of pasting it in to every one of them?

Edit: Added pseudocode

Razor view:

```
<select ... onchange="MyMethod();">

<script>
    function MyMethod()
    {
        // ajax call to my custom Handler method which returns a json object
        // dynamically fill out another dropdown with the content of the json object
    }
</script
```

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetResources(int id)
{
    return new JsonResult(
        new { 
            data = context.MyResource.Where(x => x.OtherResource.id == id).ToList()
        }
    );
}
```

It is this `OnGetResources` method that im trying to avoid duplicating.

Comment: sure.  Just create a "utility" or "helper" class.  For an example see "PaginatedList": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-paging-to-students-index

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm not sure how that solves my issue.  I've tried adding additional pseudocode to better explain my issue.

Comment: For the front-end just include a .js file in each page.  (you can put that in the header template if you use one)  The ajax can call a single endpoint, no?  You can use/include a "partial" if the front-end UI/model is always the same.

Comment: The frontend isnt a problem. You are right i can inslude a file containg my "MyMethod" which means i dont need that in all the views. However, i still need the "OnGetResources" in all the .cshtml.cs files.

Comment: You'd just call one controller via ajax that returns the data.  Your JS can call any controller and it seems like you only need a single controller to return the data here.

Comment: This is developed with razor pages - so without controllers per path. I think it would be messy to change that just for this part of the application.

Comment: default razor routing uses paths/page names... from there it's via method GET or POST.

Comment: Do you consider every .cshtml.cs file a controller in this case? I would really like to avoid creating a new actual controller.

Comment: just right-click on "Pages" and choose, "Add>Razor Page", name it "OnGetResources", open the .cs file (the controller) and add public JsonResult OnGet(int id)
{
    return new JsonResult(
        new { 
            data = context.MyResource.Where(x => x.OtherResource.id == id).ToList()
        }
}  Your ajax would send a GET to "yourdomain.com/OnGetResources?id=yourID"  (You could also create a folder in Pages, and right-click on that to add the page/controller there... then path would be yourdomain.com/yourFolder/yourpage"

Comment: Thanks now I understand better. This seems very promising. If I were to still use a custom handler method like below because I want multiple in the controller how would I call that from ajax?

`public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetResources(int id)`

Currently I have something like this:

`$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '?handler=SomeHandlerName&id=' + myID,
    success: ...,
    error: ...
)};`

Comment: Razor pages are designed to choose method via GET or POST.  So the method that handles is one of two depending on the method you used.  You don't specify a handler with Razor Pages.  Verb of GET goes to "OnGet" or "OnGetAsync"... POST to "OnPost" or "OnPostAsync".  This is nice because it will ensure that a controller has at most 2 different purposes.   (Single Responsibility Principle... except that it's really Two Responsibilities Principle, it responds to POST or GET)

Comment: Thank you - and sorry for being so slow to get it.

Comment: @pcalkins _Single_ responsibility - it processes HTTP requests for the endpoint associated with the page ;-)